# WP_Query Multiple Categories

Tags: wordpress

I've My categories Structure like this :

```
Music
 -Genre
   -Pop
   -Rock
 -Role
   -Vocalist
   -Guitarist
```

So Now I want to filter posts in such a way that a post should belong to ( either Pop or Rock) and (Vocalist)

So an or between genres and an and with the role

So speaking in wordpress terms in need multiple category_in or category_and which has category_in

Tricky right?

Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and see if it works.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'vocalist' ),
        ),
        array(
             'relation' => 'OR',
             array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => array( 'pop' ),
             ),
             array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => array( 'rock' ),
             ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```